# passing lambda as method arg and sorting map

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

i must create Sorted method, called with map arguments and lambda-expression. The method returns a sorted version of any map passed as the first argument, and the sort order is determined by the lambda expression, given as the second argument.
i created something like that(dont work correctly):

```
public Map sorted(Map map, Function<Set> funct){


    System.out.println(map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted((Comparator) funct)
       .collect(Collectors.toList()));
     return null;
}
```

Any ideas ? 
Thanks for help ;)

Comment: You are supposed to pass a `Comparator<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>` to the `sorted` method.

Comment: Function is different with Comparator

Comment: You "must"? Because it's much more readable to just `Map<K,V> sorted = new TreeMap<>(comparator); sorted.putAll(map); return sorted;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I read the question I was thinking of a more general solution where you can sort the map on either keys or values. In that case the solution looks like this:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> sorted(Map<K,V> map, Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> comparator){
    return map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(comparator)
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

If you want to want to sort by value, you can use this method like this:

```
sorted(yourMap, Entry.comparingByValue());
```

Comment: The usage example can be "shortened" as `sorted(map, Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))`.

Comment: And even shorter with `sorted(map, Entry.comparingByValue())`

Comment: Live and learn, they say! :) Realistically, I'd use the appropriate usage directly in the answer, instead of showing a somewhat complicated construct.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a *sorted map* that would be a `TreeMap` and *assuming* the comparator sorts by `Key`, it could look like this:

```
 public static <K, V> TreeMap<K, V> sorted(Map<K, V> map, Comparator<? super K> cmp) {

    return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,     
                          Map.Entry::getValue, 
                          (left, right) -> left, 
                          () -> new TreeMap<K, V>(cmp)));

}
```

And an invocation of it would look like this for example:

```
 System.out.println(sorted(map, Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Comment: Thank you for help, it was very usefull ;)

Answer (score -1):

- [Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) declared 2 generic arguments: **T** and **R**, but you only given 1 generic parameter `Set`.
- collecting a stream to a Map you can using [Collectors.toMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) rather than [Collectors.toList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) which is collecting a stream to  a List.
- [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is more like a [BiFunction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html)/[ToIntBiFunction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntBiFunction.html) due to the number of generic arguments of a Functional Interface includes **parameters & return** type.

**IF** you want to refer a `ToIntBiFunction` to a `Comparator` you can use this:

```
void sortByEntry() {
    Map<?, ?> map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<?, ?> sorted = sorted(map, this::comparingEntry);
}

<K, V> Map<K, V> sorted(Map<K, V> map, 
                        ToIntBiFunction<Entry<K, V>, Entry<K, V>> comparator) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(comparator::applyAsInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue
                                    , (v1, v2) -> v2, LinkedHashMap::new));
}

<K, V> int comparingEntry(Entry<K, V> left, Entry<K, V> right) {
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: `Comparator` is a `@FunctionalInterface`. There is therefore no need to replace it with `ToIntBiFunction`. Doing so adds complexity where there is none. This is why I downvoted this answer. If we remove that `ToIntBiFunction`, the whole answer collapses and falls back on to @Eugene's or @RobinTopper' answer, making it a duplicate.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire first, thanks for your comment. I know `Comparator` is a Functional Interface, but I want to tell how to alternative between Functional Interfaces to OP. and RobinTopper's answer is after mine.

Comment: The intent of your answer isn't really clear then. Would you mind edit your answer to make that more prominent? This way I can retract my downvote as well (since it's locked until further edit).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire It doesn't matter, I don't matter the votes. but still thanks for your feedback again.